# Can anyone help me with my currency shop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bots

I'm a little bit new to python but i know like the basics like variables and strings, i recently create a discord bot with a currency and a shop. The shop doesn't work, its meant to let me buy a ticket for the item listed (it isn't meant to store anything).Could you please help me find out where i went wrong and help me make it better or show me where i went wrong where i can find me my answer. Here is what i got for the shop (note i'm using python 3.6.4):

```
@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def buy(ctx, item):
    items = {
    "Apex Legends":[3,20],
    "Minecraft":[5,30],
    "Halo":[5,20],
    "Fortnite":[8,10],
    }
while True:
    print("Apex Legends = 3BP / Minecraft = 5BP / Halo = 5BP / Fortnite = 8BP")
    print("Account Balance bp",stash)
    choice = input("What would you like to buy?: ").strip().title()
    if choice in items:
        if items[choice][1]>0:
            if stash>=items[choice][0]:
                items[choice][1]=items[choice][1]-1
                stash= stash-items[choice][0]
                print("Thank you..!")
                print("")
            else:
                print("Sorry you don\'t enough money...")
                print("")
        else:
            print("sorry sold out")
            print("")
    else:
        print("Sorry we don\'t have that item...")
        print("")
```

If you want to see my full code on the bot its on here:
https://hastebin.com/tojadefajo.py

Comment: What is the specific error or unanticipated response from your code?

Comment: when i launch the the bot none of my other commands work and when i looking the console it shows what i can but but on on discord i want it to show on discord instead of the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You shouldn't need the `while True:` as this will enter an infinite loop since you have no `break` statements!
2. Replace all `print()` statements with `await client.say()` statements

Try this

```
@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def buy(ctx, item):
    items = {
        "Apex Legends": [3, 20],
        "Minecraft": [5, 30],
        "Halo": [5, 20],
        "Fortnite": [8, 10],
    }
    await client.say("Apex Legends = 3BP / Minecraft = 5BP / Halo = 5BP / Fortnite = 8BP")
    await client.say("Account Balance bp", stash)
    choice = input("What would you like to buy?: ").strip().title()
    if choice in items:
        if items[choice][1]>0:
            if stash>=items[choice][0]:
                items[choice][1]=items[choice][1]-1
                stash= stash-items[choice][0]
                await client.say("Thank you..!")
                await client.say("")
            else:
                await client.say("Sorry you dont enough money...")
                await client.say("")
        else:
            await client.say("sorry sold out")
            await client.say("")
    else:
        await client.say("Sorry we don't have that item...")
        await client.say("")
```